# I have got the info using api now i want to display it randomly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using an api. The response of the api consists of json data which consists of an array of 19 objects and  each array has details like `title`, `description`, `date` etc. The below function  gives me the details like `title`, `description` and  `date` of one object and i m displaying these details on my webpage in a div tag.

```
function businessDetails(data){
    var desc = data.response.deals[0].description;
    var title = data.response.deals[0].title;   
    var enddate = data.response.deals[0].end_date;
    // embedding these details into webpage using jquery
    $('#empid h3').html('About us'  );
    ......
}
```

Now I want to display the details of other remaining objects and want to display it inside that same div tag and want to keep an interval of 4 secs.

Comment: Show us a jsfiddle of what you have tried and what has gone wrong.

Comment: @Slytael cant bro coz code is very large

Comment: Then you split it down into a self contained example with only the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

```
function businessDetails(data, index){
        var desc = data.response.deals[index].description;
        var title = data.response.deals[index].title;   
        var enddate = data.response.deals[index].end_date;
          //embedding these details into webpage using jquery
        $('#empid h3').html('About us'  );
}
```

To display results sequentially:

```
for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    businessDetails(data, i);
    setTimeout(4000);
}
```

To display results randomly:

```
var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*(data.length-1))+0);
businessDetails(data, rand);
```

Comment: Thnx ,also if i want to display it randomly ,sorry i didnt mention in question where i wil use random function

Comment: Thanx sonu i try this first